# Notification icon missing with ProGuard enabled

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources, urbanairship.com

After enabling ProGuard, our push notification icon (`res/drawable-*/ic_notifications.png`) has gone missing (only an empty circle, whose colour is `notificationAccentColor`, is shown).

The icon is only referred to from Urban Airship config file (airshipconfig.properties):

```
notificationIcon = ic_notifications
notificationAccentColor = #0000CC
```

I suspect ProGuard thinks the icon is unused, and removes it. Any way to tell ProGuard to keep it?

Comment: Have to check this in another Mobile With different OS Version, i suspect this is not a issue relating to proGaurd, this issue might be ic_notification is not in the format needed for higher versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ProGuard does not remove resources. I suspect you use the `shrinkResources` feature of the Android gradle plugin? Take a look at the following page that describes how to keep certain resources from being shrunk: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html (section `Customize which resources to keep`).

Comment: Indeed, you are right. We had introduced `shrinkResources true` at the same time as enabling ProGuard, hence the confusion.

Comment: The full solution in our case: added `<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:keep="@drawable/ic_notifications"/>` in a new file `res/values/keep.xml`.